# How can I add images with my table data

Tags: php, html, css, database, image

I have made a database using phpLiteAdmin, It has many entries however they are all text or number.

I was wondering if I could add an image section  in this database or how else would I do it. The only other way I think I could do it would be by using the href tag and moving it into position. There must be a better way of doing this.

Here is my code of my php and html.

```
<head>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Car_Style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header" class="loading" style="opacity: 1";]>
    <!-- Logo -->
      <div id="logo"></div>
      <!-- Nav -->
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#intro">header</a></li>
                <li><a href="#one">Header</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two">header</a></li>
                <li><a href="#work">My Header</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Header</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- This is where all the images go from each of the entries -->
</body>

<?php

    try {
      # Connect to SQLite database
      $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:Car_Sales_Network");

      # Prepare SQL statement
      $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM Cars_On_Network' );

     # Set the Fetch Mode to Associative Array
     $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     # Run the query on the database
     $sth->execute();

    //table printout
    echo "<table>";

    # Loop through returned records
    while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
      //print_r($row);spot
      //print_r($row);

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<th>Car Make:</th>";
    echo "<th>Car Model:</th>";
    echo "<th>Car Badge:</th>";
    echo "<th>Car Price:</th>";
    echo "<th>Car Transmission:</th>";
    echo "<th>Car P Plate Legality:</th>";
    echo "<div id='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".  $row["car_make"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>".  $row["car_model"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>".  $row["car_badge"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>".  $row["price"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>".  $row["trans"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>".  $row["P_Plate_Legal"] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</div>";

    //echo $row["Game_ID"];
    echo "<br>";
  }

  echo "</table>";

 } 
 catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

This is my css.

```
* {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: black;
 }

table {
    padding: 20px;
}

th td {
   padding-right:  20px;
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-top: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
}


/*********************************************************************************/
/* Header                                                                        */
/*********************************************************************************/
#header ul li {
    color:white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.15em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

body {
    padding-top: 3em;
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1em;
    top: 0;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

#logo a {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

#nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.5em;
    top: 0;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
}

#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
}

#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

#nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Obviously it's not finished but how can I have each car with a picture.

Cheers.

Comment: Where do you store your image? Do you want to store the images directly into the database? Or do you store them on your server file system?

Comment: Either option is fine, i would prefer to put them on the database but I have a filezilla server.

Comment: @JordanSummers, dude better option is to save images in some folder and store their respective urls in database table.

Comment: yeah, but that won't display the images.

Comment: why it wont display the image?? @JordanSummers

Comment: Do you mean just provide a link to the image?

Comment: it should display, if you correctly put url in src attribute.

Comment: you have to move the file to any folder of your server, then  by the complete url of this file you will be able to show them as pictures

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you must find a way to store your image.

   We don't usually store the binary data of images in database. Instead we store the image files somewhere on your server (or 3rd party CDN).
2. Then we create a new `varchar(255)` in the database and store the URL of those images (e.g. `http://foobar.com/some/image.jpg`). For explanation, let's say we will add a column `car_image_url` in the said table.
3. Let's change the PHP code a bit to add the display column:

   ```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Car_Style.css"/>

   </head>

   <body>
       <header id="header" class="loading" style="opacity: 1";]>

                   <!-- Logo -->
                       <div id="logo">

                       </div>

                   <!-- Nav -->
                       <nav id="nav">
                           <ul>
                               <li><a href="#intro">header</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#one">Header</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#two">header</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#work">My Header</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#contact">Header</a></li>
                           </ul>
                       </nav>

               </header>

       <!-- This is where all the images go from each of the entries -->



   </body>




   <?php

   try {
     # Connect to SQLite database
     $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:Car_Sales_Network");

     # Prepare SQL statement
     $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM Cars_On_Network' );

     # Set the Fetch Mode to Associative Array
     $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     # Run the query on the database
     $sth->execute();

    //table printout
     echo "<table>";

     # Loop through returned records
     while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
       //print_r($row);spot
           //print_r($row);

       /* added these line */
       # If the image field is empty, change to dummy image
       if (empty($row['car_image_url'])) {
           $row['car_image_url'] = 'http://yourdomain.com/some/dummy.jpg';
       }
       /* // added these line */


    echo "<table>";
       echo "<th>Car Make:</th>";
       /* added this line */
       echo "<th>Car Image:</th>";
       /* // added this line */
       echo "<th>Car Model:</th>";
       echo "<th>Car Badge:</th>";
       echo "<th>Car Price:</th>";
       echo "<th>Car Transmission:</th>";
       echo "<th>Car P Plate Legality:</th>";


       echo "<div id='1'>";
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".  $row["car_make"] . "</td>";
       /* added this line */
       echo "<td><img src=\"".  $row["car_image_url"] . "\" /></td>";
       /* // added this line */
       echo "<td>".  $row["car_model"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>".  $row["car_badge"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>".  $row["price"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>".  $row["trans"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>".  $row["P_Plate_Legal"] . "</td>";


       echo "</tr>";
       echo "</div>";



         //echo $row["Game_ID"];
       echo "<br>";
     }

   echo "</table>";


     } 
   catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();

   }

   ?>
   ```
4. Style the CSS whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you @Koala Yeung, however I was wondering if you could give me just an example with this image. http://media.caranddriver.com/images/media/51/dissected-lotus-based-infiniti-emerg-e-sports-car-concept-top-image-photo-451994-s-original.jpg Thank you

Comment: I don't quite understand. You can insert the image url "[http://media.caranddriver.com/images/media/51/dissected-lotus-based-infiniti-emerg-e-sports-car-concept-top-image-photo-451994-s-original.jpg](http://media.caranddriver.com/images/media/51/dissected-lotus-based-infiniti-emerg-e-sports-car-concept-top-image-photo-451994-s-original.jpg)" into the `car_image_url` field in a database row. And the result should be fine.

Comment: Yes but when I do that all the cars that load with the database have the same image, I have 13 cars in my database and there all different.

Comment: That means it works. But I think you have insert the same url into all 13 rows. Obviously, you should insert 13 different url into the cell in the 13 different rows.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. There isn't anywhere to insert 13 different image links in the PHP code.

Comment: If you mean inserting to database from PHP, the answer is "Yes, There is". You need to learn SQL syntax, know how to form the correct SQL command. Then you need to learn how to run those commands in PHP. Are you familiar with SQL?

Comment: Not at all I'm sorry to say. I'm only 17 :)

Comment: Are you using any GUI SQL manager now? (e.g. PHPMyAdmin) How did you create your database?

Comment: Using PHPLiteAdmin. I'm guessing there similar.

Comment: You can insert / edit the 13 records to MySQL with your PHPLiteAdmin. Just use the correspondent image url in the `car_image_url` field. OK?